# setText is not displaying text in another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a program what uses setContentView to display one layout and at the same time I want to update text in another layout.

I don't find the text getting updated but retrieving values set by getText is giving updated value.

I want the value set using setText to get displayed.

```
public static class Login_fragment extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

    }
    public void login_onClick(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Login Succesful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));  
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main,null,false);
        LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.nav_linear_id);
        TextView textView=(TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.login_name_drawer);
        String viewq=textView.getText().toString();
        Log.v("First",viewq);
        textView.setText("def");
        if(textView.getParent()!=null) {
            ((ViewGroup) textView.getParent()).removeView(textView);
        }
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        viewq=textView.getText().toString();

        Log.v("Second",viewq);
    }
```

My Xml layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:id="@+id/nav_linear_id">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/login_name_drawer"
android:text="abc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the text to be updated and displays "def"

Comment: you are viewing other view which is loginlayout . and you can't see other activity layout.

Comment: But you have already start a new activity. You can pass value through intent in your _MainActivity_

Answer (score 0):

1.) Use SharedPreference to store the user values in LoginActivity. Then in the MainActivity retrieve the values from SharedPreference and set the value to the textView.

LoginActivity

```
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.
MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
     editor.putString("user", "test");
     editor.commit();
```

In MainActivity oncreate()

```
     SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.
MODE_PRIVATE);
      String user=sharedPref.getString("user","");
     TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_name_drawer);
     textView.setText(user);
```

2.) Use Intent to pass user value set the textView value in MainActivity.

LoginActivity

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("user","value");
     startActivity(intent);
```

In MainActivity onCreate()

```
      String user= getIntent().getExtras().getString("user");
      TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_name_drawer);
      textView.setText(user);
```

Hope this helps you